# ionic2/angualr2 canceling observables on home tab

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-observables

I'm trying to cancel an observable on the home tab on ionic2, it may be a bug on there side, because after now 6 hours nothing has worked.

the observable example I'm using is from this site
https://coryrylan.com/blog/intro-to-rxjs-observables-and-angular-2

I've tried ngZone, you can't clear intervals from ngZone,

I've tried

```
 ionViewWillLeave() {
      this.disposable.dispose();
      clearInterval(this.home_game_timer);

  }
```

nothing works..
here's the code... this code is on the home tab

```
getGame(){

var link = 'https://gamerholic.com/******';
var data_post = JSON.stringify({game:this.game,uid:this.data.uid,device:this.device_id,session:this.session});
let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

return this.http.post(link, data_post, options) // ...using post request
.map(data => data.json())
.catch(this.handleError)
.subscribe((data) =>{
  this.game_data = data

  if(this.game_data.success){
    this.game = this.game_data.games[0].id,
    this.game_data = this.game_data.games[0]
        this.gameStream$ = new Observable(observer=>{
          this.home_game_timer = setInterval(()=>{

              if(this.gone<1){
                var link = 'https://gamerholic.com/****';
                var data = JSON.stringify({game:this.game,uid:this.uid});
                let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' });
                let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
                return this.http.post(link, data,options)
                .map(data => data.json())
                .catch(this.handleError)
                .subscribe((data) =>{
                  var d = data
                  observer.next(d)
                })
              }

            },1000)

            return(()=>{
              clearInterval(this.home_game_timer);
            })
        })

        this.disposable = this.gameStream$.subscribe((data)=>{
        this.timer_data = data
        this.list_players = data
        console.log(this.timer_data)
      })

      }
  })

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel an observable, you need to unsubscribe form it. What you are doing is creating an observable that has some teardown logic. So far so good.

```
return(()=>{
          clearInterval(this.home_game_timer);
        })
```

This snippet of teardown logic however, is not executed until you explicitly unsubscribe from the observable. So you set a clearInterval, but this method is never called, since the observable is never unsubscribed to. What you should do is actually unsubscribe at some point.

```
this.disposable = this.gameStream$.subscribe((data)=>{
    this.timer_data = data
    this.list_players = data
    console.log(this.timer_data)
  })

this.disposable.unsubscribe(); // ==> this will trigger the teardown logic to be called
```

The place where you can call this can vary on your needs. When do you need it to be called? 
If it's at destroy time of your component, you could use the destroy lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 0):

The work around I found is to set a local storage of the page view
on the home tab

```
this.page_view      = 'global'
localStorage.setItem('page_view','global')
```

i pass the page view to the service

```
this.globalService$.timer(this.page_view,this.device_id,this.game,this.uid)
.map(data => data.json())
.catch(this.handleError)
.subscribe(
       (data) =>{
         this.game_data = data
       })
```

from the service I match the passed page view with the local storage page view

```
timer(page_view,device_id,game,uid){

let pv =  localStorage.getItem('page_view')
if(page_view==pv){

  var link = 'https://gamerholic.com/****';
  var data_post = JSON.stringify({game:game,uid:uid,device:device_id});
  let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
  let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
  return this.http.post(link, data_post, options) // ...using post request

  }
 }
```

now the timer only runs if the page views match...